# Get Result form AsyncTask to set on another value

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i want to get the result form AsyncTask , i can show with system.out.println(), but i want keep that result and save on a new attribute, outside from AsyncTask;

OnTaskFinished.java

```
    public interface OnTaskFinished
{
    public void onFeedRetrieved(String feeds);
}
```

RetrieveFeedTask.java

```
    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    String HTML_response= "";
    String VideoLink;

    public String getVideoLink() {
        return VideoLink;
    }


    public void setVideoLink(String videoLink) {
        this.VideoLink = videoLink;
    }


    OnTaskFinished onOurTaskFinished;


    public RetrieveFeedTask(OnTaskFinished onTaskFinished)
    {
        onOurTaskFinished = onTaskFinished;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]); // enter your url here which to download

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                //System.out.println(inputLine);


                if(inputLine.toString().contains("<meta property='og:image'"))
                {
                    String str =inputLine;
                    str = str.replace("<meta property='og:image' content=\"", "");

                    //System.out.println(str);
                    VideoLink=str;
                    setVideoLink(str);
                    inputLine=str;





                }


                HTML_response += inputLine;
            }
            br.close();

            //System.out.println("Done");

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return VideoLink;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String feed)
    {
        onOurTaskFinished.onFeedRetrieved(feed);
    }
}
```

and here is how i call
Main.java

```
String data;   
....


new RetrieveFeedTask(new OnTaskFinished()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onFeedRetrieved(String feeds)
                    {
                        System.out.println(feeds);

                    }
                }).execute(VideoUrl);
```

i want that feeds get out and set on a diferente value outside from RetrieveFeedTask
on this case set the result on data;

Comment: Where do you want to set it? Please clarify your question.

Comment: on main i have a String data; i want set the result there.

Comment: What is "Main.java"? Is it an `Activity`?

Comment: You should be able to simply assign a value if the method is not static. Like this: `Main.this.data = feeds;`

Comment: allways return me null , i fixed using toString.. thanks